# Since I have used `have rolled` should I use `had rolled down` or `have rolled down`?

Tags: grammar, tense, verbs, grammaticality-in-context

Since I have used `have rolled` should I use `had rolled down` or `have rolled down`?

> When the driver drives and you have rolled the window of the car down
> and you are sitting in the back seat, what will you do if the driver
> throws a litter out of the car and the litter enters through the
> window that you had rolled down and the litter hits your face?

Comment: *litter* is uncountable, so you can't say "the driver throws *a* litter".  Just say "the driver throws litter".

Answer (score 2):

Both "have" and "had" are possible here, and in context there isn't much difference in meaning.  That is because you are being repetitive, so the fact about the window being rolled down is already known.  It doesn't much matter now if you use the past or present perfect.

In fact this sentence would benefit from some serious shortening. You can cut "driver drives" (what else do drivers do?) and I don't think anybody actually "rolls down" windows anymore. Of course you are "sitting in a seat" (that's what seats are for), and if the piece of litter enters through the window, of course the window must be open. With a bit of effort you could cut this down from three lines (on my screen) to one.

> What would you do if the driver throws litter out but it comes back in and hits you in the face.

Comment: That's a bit drastic! _If you were in the back seat of a car with the window open, what would you do if the driver threw out some litter and it came back in and hit you in the face?_

Comment: I'm feeling drastic!